# Resharper force line break before dot

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper

How do you force line breaks before the dot?

For example:

```
Method()
    .CallAnother()
        .AndAnother()
```

I also want to flow the following:

```
Bind<IService>().ToMethod(ctx => new DataRetrievalService()).InSingletonScope().Named(
            "LIVESERVICE");
```

As:

```
Bind<IDataRetrievalService>()
    .ToMethod(
        ctx => new AdobeDataRetrievalService())
    .InSingletonScope()
    .Named("LIVESEARCHRETRIEVALSERVICE");
```

This may be the same thing or it could be something different??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vote for [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-88220) on the JetBrains YouTrack site for ReSharper.  Hopefully if it garners enough support, it will be in the next minor release.